# Octave matrix to be filled based on condition

Tags: matlab, matrix, octave

I have a column vector with indices.

```
a = [10, 10, 10, 5, 5, 3, 3]
```

I'd like to create a 7x10 matrix with zeros but each row has one column with 1 and the position of that column is determined by the value in the vector `a`.

Right now I'm doing the following:

```
for i = 1:length(a)
    b(i, a(i)) = 1;
end
```

It does the right thing:

```
b =

   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

But I'm wondering if there is a function or a syntax sugar that allows me to do it without a loop.

I have to do it many places and sometimes the matrices are quite large and I'd prefer to do it without a loop.

Comment: Try `sub2ind`, let me know if you can't figure it out.

Comment: @rayryeng You're right, that duplicate question does solve my problem. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. Take care!